# Running Ruby scripts from command line

Tags: ruby, execute

I have a 2 scripts:

test1.rb

```
require 'test2.rb'
puts "hello"
```

test2.rb

```
puts "test"
```

I'm running this by executing `ruby test2.rb test1.rb`.

But only `test` is printed out and not `hello`.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the ruby command?

Comment: No, could you please direct me to the relevant documents within the documentation please?

Comment: `ruby -h`: "Usage: ruby [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]".
So the ruby command takes a single program file, not multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to run `ruby test1.rb` and the `require` statement should pull in test2.rb for you - you don't need to put it on the command line as well.  (That will try and run test2.rb, passing the string 'test1.rb' as an argument, which is not what you want here)

Edit: the `require` statement does not look in the current directory by default when trying to find 'test2.rb'.  You can explicitly specify it by changing it to:

`require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test2.rb'`

Comment: When I do that it says theres no such file to load -- test2.rb

Comment: File.dirname("C:/Ruby192") + '/test2.rb' doesnt seem to be working either. Error: no such file to load C://test2.rb. Doesnt seem to be forming the path correctly.

Comment: when it says `__FILE__`, you need to actually write that, not 'Ruby192'!

Comment: Ashish's answer is also correct - `require_relative 'test2.rb'` also works for this.

Answer (score 2):

in test1.rb do (assuming test2.rb is in same directory, otherwise give its path relative to test1.rb)

```
require_relative 'test2.rb'
puts "hello"
```

and on the command line just do `ruby test1.rb`

Comment: yeah its a Kernel function and I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well

```
require './test2.rb'
puts "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some explanation how you can solve your problem, but not what is going wrong.

With `ruby test2.rb test1.rb` you call the ruby script with the **parameter** test1.rb.

You have access to the parameters in the constant `ARGV`.

An example with this script:

```
puts "test"
puts 'ARGV= %s' % ARGV
```

The result when you call it:

```
C:\Temp>ruby test.rb test2.rb
test
ARGV= test2.rb
```

So you could also write a program like:

```
require_relative ARGV.first
```

The first parameter defines a script to be loaded.

Or if you want to load many scripts you could use:

```
ARGV.each{|script| require_relative script }
```